# Overlap two objects to share the same stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two rectangles with stroke width of 2px.
How do I go about putting them side by side such that they share the same adjacent stroke border of 2px?

I tried dragging the rectangles to fit them into the stroke but there is no snapping. Is there a better way to do this?

Stroke border of 2 x 2px
[image]

Rectangles share the same stroke.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw one rectangle and then draw a 2px line and center it in the rectangle.

[image]

Unless there's some reason you *must* have two separate rectangles.

---

<sup>(Assumption that all strokes are set to the *default* stroke alignment, which is centered on their respective paths)</sup>

Realistically, if two rectangles are *actually* butted against each other, there is no variation in the appearance of a stroke....

[image]

Yellow boxes are all the same width.... as are the strokes. However this is two separate rectangles.

[image]

[image]

The key may be to use **Outline Mode** (View > Outline) to ensure your rectangles actually do butt against each other. Outline mode can be an *invaluable* feature if you are trying to be precise in positioning. There is simply no way to be as accurate working strictly in Preview Mode.

[image]

Enlargement:
[image]

Because if you have a gap or overlap between the rectangles:

[image]

.... and everything is stroked the same color, all you'll see in Preview Mode (View > Preview) is the apparent "thicker" stroke:

[image]

What actually happens is the two strokes overlap each other and are **not** aligned properly:

[image]

So, basically, this issue is **ultimately because your two rectangles are not butting against each other.**

Correctly aligned objects will have correctly aligned strokes which, when overlapping will not give the appearance of a thicker stroke.

You may also find it helpful to ensure `Use Preview Bounds` is **not** checked in the **Preferences**. This will allow snapping to use *actual* object paths for snapping rather than their preview containing the stroke appearance.

Comment: I am drawing three rectangles, how can i distribute the lines at 1/3 and 2/3 wdith respectively?

Comment: @Carrein you can make the rectangle say 99px long, and draw a line every 33px (Just to make things simple)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 way to do this.

First Way:

1. Open Apperance Panel, set Align Stroke to Center to all rectangle (if not set)
2. Select both rectangles, then select first once 
   again (it will be a 'key object'), then open Align Panel (Shift-F7), set Distribute Spacing =0 and hit 'Horisontal Distribute Space'.

Second Way

1. Delete second rectangle.
2. Select first, then open Effect->Distort & Transform->Transform. Set 'Move Horisontal' to rectangular width, set Copy=1.